# how can I cast LPVOID into struct

Tags: winapi, networking, rust

I started learning Rust WinApi. I need to iterate over all network computers using winapi crate. This is my code:

```
fn enumerate_network_computers(lpnr: LPNETRESOURCEW) -> u32 {
    unsafe {
        let mut h_enum: HANDLE = 0 as PVOID;
        let mut cb_entries: DWORD = 9999;
        let mut cb_buffer: DWORD = 16384;
        let lpnr_local: LPVOID = GlobalAlloc(GPTR, cb_buffer.try_into().unwrap());

        let mut dw_err = WNetOpenEnumW(RESOURCE_GLOBALNET, RESOURCETYPE_ANY, 0, lpnr, &mut h_enum);
        
        if dw_err != NO_ERROR {
            return dw_err;
        }

        loop {
            dw_err = WNetEnumResourceW(h_enum, &mut cb_entries, lpnr_local, &mut cb_buffer);

            println!("{:#?}", lpnr_local);
            
            
            if dw_err == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS {
                break;
            }
        }

        dw_err
    }
}
```

So, my code works great! But I can't cast `LPVOID` to `NETRESOURCEW` to iterate over structure... I've already tried `.try_into()`, `lpnr_local as NETRESOURCEW`. But I get error: the trait `From<*mut winapi::ctypes::c_void>` is not implemented for `NETRESOURCEW`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LPVOID` is a pointer but `NETRESOURCEW` is not so you cannot cast between them. Remember that the prefix `LP` stands for *long pointer*.

So try casting `lpnr_local as LPNETRESOURCEW` instead.

Alternatively you can avoid the Microsoft-ism and do `lpnr_local as *const NETRESOURCEW`.

Note that in order to access the members of that structure you have to dereference the pointer. I'd do something like this:

```
let nr = &*(lpnr_local as *const NETRESOURCEW);
println!("{:#?}", nr);
```

Comment: possible, there are two or more strcutures. how can I iterate over all of them?

Comment: I've tried `for n in nr` and `nr.iter()` but getting same error: `NETRESOURCEW` is not an iterator

Comment: I guess that you should do as in C. Something like this (untested): `for n in 0..nr { let r = &*((lpnr_local as *const u8).offset(n * std::mem::size_of::<NETRESOURCEW>()) as *const NETRESOURCEW); ...`.

Comment: @NikoBosko You could also just start with a slice of `NETRESOURCEW` structures (or rather [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) thereof), and pass [`as_mut_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_mut_ptr) into the call to `WNetEnumResourceW`. Once it returns, you can then just iterate over the slice. Still unsafe, but far less prone to subtle bugs when manually performing pointer arithmetic.